# eclipse disable completion of xml comment

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to disable Eclipse auto-inserting `-->` after I type `<!--` (opening of XML comment)?

I have tried removing a template for "comment" (`<!-- ${cursor} -->`) in Preferences->XML->XML Files->Editor->Templates, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> XML ->XML Files -> Editor -> Typing

Uncheck `Comments` checkbox in Automatically close section. Click Apply. Should work